# Will a transaction in SQL Server procedure rollback if a sub procedure failed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have 4 stored procedures setup as a domino (A B C D.) By domino I mean, if I execute A, A will also execute B, then B executes C and finally C will execute D. If I execute C then C will execute the one after it which is D.

When I execute A I want to make sure (A, B, C, and D) execute successfully before I commit otherwise I want all 4 to rollback.

Here is how my procedure are setup currently

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[A] @someValue VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO tableA(col1, col2)
    VALUES(@someValue, GETDATE());

    EXEC [dbo].[B] @@IDENTITY

    COMMIT;

END;



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[B] @aID
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO tableB(col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES(@someValue, GETDATE(), @aID);

    EXEC [dbo].[C] @@IDENTITY

    COMMIT;

END;



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[C] @bID
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO tableC(col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES(@someValue, GETDATE(), @bID);

    EXEC [dbo].[D] @@IDENTITY

    COMMIT;

END;


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[D] @cID
AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO tableD(col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES(@someValue, GETDATE(), @cID);

    COMMIT;

END
```

How can I ensure that either all procedures get committed or all rolls back?

Comment: See this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82681/how-to-rollback-when-3-stored-procedures-are-started-from-one-stored-procedure

Comment: And don't use @@IDENTITY. You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead. If there is a trigger that inserts into an audit table the way you coded this it will get that identity instead.

Comment: @SeanLange That insert statement in actually in a loop. and for each record inserted B will insert other records. What would be the benefit of using SCOPE_IDENTITY instead?

Comment: @AaronD does this mean I should wrap each of my SP into a try catch block?

Comment: You can read about the differences here. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you. SCOPE_IDENTITY it is :)

Comment: you need xact_abort or try-catch

Comment: Use one try/catch with rollback and put all of the SPs within it.  The top answer on that post will explain why and give a handful of other options for these situations^^

Comment: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)